# Importing Bootstrap with NPM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, import, npm-install

So I'm new to NPM & Webpack and I have a question about how to `import` bootstrap. Right now what I know is `npm install --save bootstrap` will put bootstrap as a dependency in my `package.json`. I have done the same with jQuery and to import into a script that uses jQuery all I have to do is say `import $ from 'jquery';` and no more errors saying "Where in the hell jQuery?"

Is there a similar approach for importing bootstrap?

I looked in the `node_modules` directory and found the bootstrap directory has a css & js directory that holds `.js` & `.css` files some being minimizations.

Do I just call those in the index.html like so:
`<link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">` I ask this because I have a `.gitignore` set up to not see `node_modules` so I'm not sure if the browser when it reads down the page would even recognize `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install react-bootstrap`

[React Bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io)

(didn't realize their was a specific module just for react)